# How to store data into a vector, then re-use

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to save data into an array, to re-use again, the data is in the following format and is from 1964-2013, this is just a snippet, any help would be great, cheers.

```
 a     b    c       d        e       f     

1964   9   20.5     8.8       0    37.4     
1964  10   13.6     4.2       5    77.8     
1964  11   11.8     4.7       3    45.5     
1964  12    7.7     0.1      17    65.1     
1965   1    7.3     0.8      14    74.6     
1965   2    6.5     0.1      13     3.3
```

This is the where im up to with the code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Weather
{
  int a;
  int b;
  double c;
  double d;
  int e;
  double f;
  double g;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Weather> data_weather;
  string line;
  std::ifstream myfile ("weatherdata.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline(myfile, line) )
        {

    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    int a_d, b_d, c_d, d_d, e_d, f_d, g_;
    buffer >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f >> g;

    data_weather.push_back(Weather());
    data_weather.back().a = a_d;
    data_weather.back().b = b_d;
    data_weather.back().c = c_d;
    data_weather.back().d = d_d;
    data_weather.back().e = e_d;
    data_weather.back().f = f_d;
    data_weather.back().g = g_d;

    cout << line << endl;

        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "unable to open file";

        scat::pause("\nPress <ENTER> to end the program.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Reuse what? The vector? An entry in the structure? Something else?

Comment: is what ive done correct? in the way of storing the data in the vector? also how do i read out several different lines etc?

Comment: @jaylad Your recent edit replaced the entire content of the question with "111111". That wasn't intentional, was it? (I've rolled it back for now.)

Answer (score 2):

Example for the vector usage..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> student_marks(20);

    for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter marks for student #" << i+1 
             << ": " << flush;
        cin >> student_marks[i];
    }
    // ... Do some stuff with the values

return 0;
}
```

Below can help you for better understanding...

http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/vectors.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't tell us what's the problem you're having, I can only guess. I noticed you're reading everything in `int` variables.

```
int year, mm, tmax, tmin, af, rain, sun;
buffer >> year >> mm >> tmax >> tmin >> af >> rain >> sun;
```

The format of your data suggest you need a floating point data type (for `tmax`, `tmin` and `rain` at least).

The `sun` column also can't be parsed as an `int` (there are only minus characters there). Reading into `sun` variable will fail and as you haven't initialized it, you'll invoke undefined behaviour in this line:

```
data_weather.back().sun = sun; // sun's value is indeterminate, reading it is UB
```

Unless you're absolutely sure input operation can't fail (in case of user input, that's practically never) I suggest you get in the habit of checking for success:

```
if (!(buffer >> year >> mm >> tmax >> tmin >> af >> rain >> sun)) {
    // something went wrong
}
```

Comment: would that be as simple as float tmax, tmin, rain;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure you skip the first 2 lines because they are not numerical values. Also, as another person said, make sure you read a `double` for the values you want to store as a `double` and `int` for the values you want to read as `int`.

Example:

```
double value1, value2;
int value3, value4;
stream >> value1 >> value3 >> value 2 >> value 4;
```

Next, you can create a `Weather` object and the push the object into the vector:

```
Weather objName = {year, month, tempmax, tempmin, airfrost, rain, sun};
data_weather.push_back(objName);
```

You can access each element of the vector by `vector[index]` or `vector.at(index)`.
You can modify those values in that way as well:

```
data_weather[2].year = newYear;
```

To print you can loop through the vector and print out the values:

```
for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); it++) {
  cout << it.year << " " << it.month << endl; //Or any other values you want
```

Comment: one last question, some months further down the file have data missing marked "--", how do i account for that, also do i need to do some form of error checking?

Comment: You can store each value as a `string` and then if you want to use it as a numerical value, you could convert it to a `double` or `int`. Also, will all of the input files possibly have months or other values marked as --?

Comment: yes there are several occasion where data is missing for whatever reason, this data is either marked "--" as unknown or "*" for predicted data

Comment: Your best bet would be to store everything as a string, and convert them to `int` or `double` when needed.

Comment: ok, storing everything as a string and converting to int or double depending on what i was after...is that similar to the above code, as im not familiar with that, thanks

Comment: Just use `std::string` and change your variable types to `string`. Then read in the data from the stream. You can use `atoi()` or `atof()` to convert `std::string` to `int` or `double`.

Comment: thanks, to loop through the vector as you showed me above, im getting an error with it.year and it.month, stating has no member "year" & "month"

Comment: You have to be using c++11 to use the `auto` keyword. Try `it->year` instead.

Comment: thanks OGH that worked using -> instead, as you mentioned i need to ignore the first 2 lines as there not numerical, to do this would i use GotoLine(myfile, 3);? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done it works. There are other ways of doing, like creating the structure first, filling it with data, and push that:

```
Weather weather;

buffer >> weather.year >> weather.month
       >> weather.tempmax >> weather.tempmin
       >> weather.airfrost >> weather.rain >> weather.sun;

data_weather.push_back(weather);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i can i call out several months worth of data say for tmax? and use it do a calculation

Comment: @jaylawson You might use e.g. [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with a special predicate to copy specific entries to a new vector.